# WideImage output as strange characters instead of image

Tags: php, jpeg, wideimage

I am trying to showing cropped images as thubmnails with WideImage.

I made a function with an array of filenames as parameter ($images) where I produce my html

```
foreach ($images as $img) {
    $pathToThumb = str_replace("/upload/images", "/upload/images/thumbs", $img);
    $thumb = WideImage::loadFromFile($pathToThumb)->crop('center', 'center', 150, 100)->output('jpg', 100); ?>
    <div class="lingerie">
        <a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="<?php print $img; ?>">
            <img src="<?php echo $thumb; ?>" alt=""/>
        </a>
    </div>
<?php } ? ?>
```

For now, all I get is

����JFIF``���u i$�J�$��]5�����j4���%�o�WEʴ���^[7��|��6�d��P$g�bx�e��wh����N��*c��rp=Oz��h�F�Z��"��u8q�oN��la_28�g�����1��2G��1^Uy�EJ��'��|��9F[����Vn��2m�j�i��ַߣ,4��*�? *����2zp3�P[|���>���1���8$u��+cQ��:x���-�II^r1��{U�+O��T�x��*b��3����zv�m �)b�U��j�+'B�`m������a����T��r���Tq�1�*����*�{D_s�!AbG;v��������/i5��u�ݶ]�����M�]�]���#$Z���74"+ar]�-�',�B���J��W�}KY�/7H#��7�3-n�=���v�Ps�3�C~��N��h��j�q��6�����- and so on

What is the reason for these weird digits?

Comment: That's the actual image content, not a link to the image. You need to write the image somewhere first.

Comment: I don't need to save the image, just show it. Do I need to create a temporary file with a GD-function?